# Wrapper for JQuery's ajax function. Callback fired, but no params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I very new to JavaScript, so question may be dummy.
I do a lot of GET and POST requests in my code, so I decided to write wrapper function to call jQuery's ajax function

```
/**
 * Makes Get request
 * @param url URL
 * @param successCallback function triggered when request is successfully proceeded
 * @param failCallback  function triggered is case of failed request
 */
function getRequest(url,successCallback,failCallback){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        timeout: 3000,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            successCallback(data,textStatus,jqXHR);
        },
        error: failCallback(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
    });
}
```

I call it this way:

```
url = "/api/info";
function onSuccess(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
        $("#result").html("Hostname is "+data.hostname);
}
function onFail(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
        $("#result").html("Shit happens");
}
//fire request
getRequest(url,onSuccess(),onFail());
```

Callback is fired, but data is undefined.

Comment: I see a fundamental misunderstanding of how functions work in JS. I suggest you look up the difference between a function object and a function call.

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` print in `successCallback`?

Comment: also change `getRequest(url,onSuccess(),onFail());` to `getRequest(url,onSuccess,onFail);`

Comment: @Fabricator, `getRequest(url,onSuccess,onFail);` causes `Uncaught ReferenceError: jqXHR is not defined` while response from backend is successfully proceeded

Comment: change `error: failCallback(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)` to `error: failCallback`

Answer (score 3):

Finally I fixed it by rewritting function like this:

```
function getRequest(url,successCallback,failCallback){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        timeout: 3000,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            successCallback(data,textStatus,jqXHR);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
            failCallback(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown);
        }
    });    
}
```

And usage is:

```
getRequest(url,onSuccess,onFail);
```

as @Fabricator pointed